# How to structure the code in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

How is it possible to structure the code in PhpStorm without tap every tab for each line?

I mean, witch key I need to press to structure the code?

I tried a lot of key combinations, but without success. Unfortunately, I do not find the right page in the doc

Comment: Do you mean the "Reformat Code" option? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/reformatting-source-code.html

Comment: Please clarify what do you man by "structure the code"? Do you just want to have correct indents? If so `Code | Auto-Indent Lines`. Do you want actual code reformat (where it may add/remove line breaks etc)? If so -- `Code | Reformat Code`. **P.S.** Shortcut depend on Keymap used -- but you can clearly see them when accessing those actions via menu.

Comment: @lazyOne thank you for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To `reformat code` on mac the default is `Ctrl + alt + L`, but you can find it under Menu `Code -> Reformat Code`.

You can also assign your own keys if you want, by going on `PHPStorm->Preferences->Keymap` and in the search bar you can tap `Reformat Code` (again this is on mac, on windows I think this is under `File->Preferences`)